# JQueryUI Accordion Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to set up the JQueryUI Accordion for my webpage. I have it working for the most part, but it seems to be excluding some text that I intended to include under one of the headers.

The text "Office for Macs" and the link below it should be under the "Remote Access Support" header, but it seems to be showing up outside of the Accordion.

I've tried changing the header option several times to no avail. Here's what I have now:

HTML:

```html
<div class="category-tree">
    <section class="category">
        <h2>
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204910-Application-Support">Application Support</a>
        </h2>
        <i class="category-empty">
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204910-Application-Support">empty</a>
        </i>
    </section>

    <section class="category">
        <h2>
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204790-Mac-Support">Mac Support</a>
        </h2>
        <i class="category-empty">
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204790-Mac-Support">empty</a>
        </i>
    </section>

    <section class="category">
        <h2>
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208874-Windows-Support">Windows Support</a>
        </h2>
        <i class="category-empty">
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208874-Windows-Support">empty</a>
        </i>
    </section>

    <section class="category">
        <h2>
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208864-Mobile-Device-Support">Mobile Device Support</a>
        </h2>
        <i class="category-empty">
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208864-Mobile-Device-Support">empty</a>
        </i>
    </section>

    <section class="category">
        <h2>
            <a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208854-Remote-Access-Support">Remote Access Support</a>
        </h2>

        <section class="section">
            <h3>
                <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592804-Office-for-Windows">Office for Windows</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="article-list">
                <li >
                    <a href="/hc/en-us/articles/202884164-How-to-delegate-access-to-your-mailbox">How to delegate access to your mailbox</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section class="section">
            <h3>
                <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">Office for Macs</a>
            </h3>  
            <i class="section-empty">
                <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">empty</a>
            </i>
        </section>
    </section>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```js
$(function() {
$( ".category-tree").accordion({
collapsible: true,
active: false,
header: 'h2'
});
});
```

I created a Fiddle that includes all relevant code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ukq45wts/

Any thoughts on how I can tell JQueryUI to include the "Office for Macs" text under the last header?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I indented your markup to make it more readable, if you prefer it how it was, please revert the edit.

Comment: Approved the edit. Thanks Waxen - I'm still trying to learn the formatting tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

What is `<i class="section-empty">`?

It should be `<li class="section-empty">`

Comment: You're certainly right - it should be "li", but the HTML is actually created by the the web service I'm using (I don't have direct control over how the HTML is generated). I'm trying to use jQueryUI to take the automatically-generated HTML and put it into a Accordion. Does that make sense? I tried changing them all to "li" in the Fiddle, but it didn't fix the issue. Thank you for the question.

Answer (score 0):

remove `<section class="section">` above the 'Office For Macs'  and move within the containing  like so:

```
<section class="section">
   <h3>
      <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592804-Office-for-Windows">Office for Windows</a>
   </h3>
<ul class="article-list">
   <li >
      <a href="/hc/en-us/articles/202884164-How-to-delegate-access-to-your-mailbox">How to delegate access to your mailbox</a>
   </li>
   <h3>
      <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">Office for Macs</a>
   </h3>  
   <li class="section-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">empty</a></li>
</ul>
</section>

</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ukq45wts/3/

Comment: Come to http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/platoon/2832655391579583434/ n00b =D lol

Comment: A good suggestion, but I wouldn't have the ability to remove that tag, as it is automatically generated by the web service. For good measure, I removed it from the Fiddle, but it didn't actually fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the  under Remote Access Support in order to include Office for Mac sunder it.

HTML Markup

```
 <div class="category-tree"><section class="category">
  <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204910-Application-Support">Application Support</a></h2>
  <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204910-Application-Support">empty</a></i>
</section>

<section class="category">
  <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204790-Mac-Support">Mac Support</a></h2>
  <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204790-Mac-Support">empty</a></i>
</section>

<section class="category">
  <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208874-Windows-Support">Windows Support</a></h2>
  <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208874-Windows-Support">empty</a></i>
</section>

<section class="category">
  <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208864-Mobile-Device-Support">Mobile Device Support</a></h2>
  <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208864-Mobile-Device-Support">empty</a></i>
</section>

<section class="category">
  <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208854-Remote-Access-Support">Remote Access Support</a></h2>
  <section class="section">
  <h3>
 <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592804-Office-for-Windows">Office for Windows</a>
</h3>

  <ul class="article-list">
    <li >

  <a href="/hc/en-us/articles/202884164-How-to-delegate-access-to-your-mailbox">How to delegate access to your mailbox</a>
</li>

  </ul>

<section class="category">
  <h3>
 <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">Office for Macs</a>
</h3>

  <i class="section-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">empty</a></i>
</section>



</section>

</section>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukq45wts/2/)

**UPDATE**

In Jquery you are specifying that the header for the accordion will be a h2 tag. The accordion control will then directly check for the content in the tag which is just below it as a sibling. Hence If you need to add multiple sections (In case of remote access support) you need to wrap it up in another section ( I named it multiple sections) and then define it.

So the HTML code will look like:

```
<div class="category-tree">
    <section class="category">
         <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204910-Application-Support">Application Support</a></h2>
 <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204910-Application-Support">empty</a></i>

    </section>
    <section class="category">
         <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204790-Mac-Support">Mac Support</a></h2>
 <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200204790-Mac-Support">empty</a></i>

    </section>
    <section class="category">
         <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208874-Windows-Support">Windows Support</a></h2>
 <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208874-Windows-Support">empty</a></i>

    </section>
    <section class="category">
         <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208864-Mobile-Device-Support">Mobile Device Support</a></h2>
 <i class="category-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208864-Mobile-Device-Support">empty</a></i>

    </section>
    <section class="category">
         <h2><a href="/hc/en-us/categories/200208854-Remote-Access-Support">Remote Access Support</a></h2>

        <section class="multipleSections">
            <section class="section">
                 <h3>
 <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592804-Office-for-Windows">Office for Windows</a>
</h3>

                <ul class="article-list">
                    <li> <a href="/hc/en-us/articles/202884164-How-to-delegate-access-to-your-mailbox">How to delegate access to your mailbox</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                 <h3>
 <a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">Office for Macs</a>
</h3>
 <i class="section-empty"><a href="/hc/en-us/sections/200592794-Office-for-Macs">empty</a></i>

            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle - Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/ukq45wts/5/)

Comment: This certainly works, and it makes me believe I might need to manually create this HTML code rather than use the automatically-generated (as I posted). Before I go down that road, do you know of any way to make JQuery ignore those section tags? It would be much easier if I didn't have to maintain this code manually going forward. Thanks V31!

Comment: which section tag you want to ignore?

Comment: Ideally all of them. If JQuery could be configured to ignore the section tags, it wouldn't cut off the "Office for Macs" text. In other words, I set the javascript to look for the div tag, and I set the header to look for h2 tags - why is the section tag being considered the stopping point for the last header? Thanks